# BaseViewModel for every Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way that I can pass the same BaseViewModel for every request without returning either the BaseViewModel or something that inherits from the BaseViewModel for each view? I'm using a shared view (_layout.cshtml).

Comment: Your question is highly confusing.  You want to pass a BaseViewModel but you don't want to pass a BaseViewModel?  You need to write more clearly.

Comment: I want to have the data and values for the BaseViewModel for every request without having to pass it back in each ActionResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way. If your view or layout is strongly typed to a class `BaseViewModel` you need to return an instance of this class (or a derived class) from each controller action that is rendering this view.

As an alternative to the base view model approach you may checkout the [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helper in order to encapsulate some common view functionality.

Comment: That's what I had thought. Was hoping that the community had a cool trick around it though. :(